# Prove that $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \mathrm {sgn} \sin (\frac{1}{x})$ does not exist.

Tags: real-analysis, limits

My progress:

Using the sequential criterion for limits, I constructed two sequences $(x_n), (y_n)$ with $\lim(x_n)=\lim(y_n)=0$, such that $\lim(f(x_n))\neq \lim(f(y_n))$, where $f(x)=\sin\frac 1 x$.

So, $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \sin (\frac{1}{x})$ does not exist.

I also showed separately in the same way that  $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0}  \mathrm{sgn} (x)$ does not exist.

I know that  $$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} f(x)=M ,\,  \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} g(x)=N \Rightarrow \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} (fg)(x)=MN$$

Here, I have two functions $f,g$ which do not have limits at $x=0$. Does it follow from here that $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} (fg)(x)$ also doesn't exist?

Is it any other way to approach the problem?

Comment: Look for the limits of $\frac{1}{x}$ from negative and positive sides. I think that argument can be easily used too and is very easy one.

Comment: Should I do that using $\epsilon-\delta$ definition?

Comment: Depends upon how much formal and rigorous you want it to be.

Comment: I need it to be formal but also easy, I'm a beginner at analysis.... :) Thanks! :)

Comment: Is it $\lim_{x \to 0} \mathrm {sgn} (x) \sin x$?

Comment: @AaronMaroja no, it is $\frac1x$....

Comment: I'm sorry, my point was $\mathrm {sgn } (x)$

Comment: @AaronMaroja it is given as $sgnsin(\frac1x)$ in my exercise... :)

Comment: Then you are supposed to be using composition rather than product of functions.

Comment: Regarding the limit of the product of functions, let $f = g = \operatorname{sgn}(x)$

Comment: @AaronMaroja I don't know how to do that...

Comment: @GFauxPas ah, ok, so it is not true! thank you :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint** do you know for which $\theta$s you have $\sin \theta = 1$? how about $\sin \theta = -1$? Can you choose a sequence of $(x_n)$ and $(y_n)$ converging to 0 such that $\sin (1/x_n) = 1$ always and $\sin (1/y_n) = -1$ always?

Comment: sin$\theta=1$ for $\dfrac{(4n+1)\pi}{2}$ and sin$\theta=-1$ for $\dfrac{(4n-1)\pi}{2}$. So I will choose $(x_n)=\dfrac{1}{\frac{(4n+1)\pi}{2}}$ and $(y_n)=\dfrac{1}{\frac{(4n-1)\pi}{2}}$, right? Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: @Diya: That looks fine.

Comment: Ok, so that proves that $lim_{x \rightarrow 0} sin(\frac1x)$ does not exist. How do I incorporate the $sgn$ part?

Comment: @Diya: the signum function $\mathrm{sgn}$ returns $+1$ if its argument is positive, and $-1$ if the argument is negative. In particular: $\mathrm{sgn}(+1) = +1$ and $\mathrm{sgn}(-1) = -1$. So for the sequences $(x_n)$ and $(y_n)$ that you constructed above, you have $\mathrm{sgn} \sin(x_n) = \sin(x_n) = +1$ and similarly for $y_n$.

Comment: I got it now, thank you! :)

Comment: In fact, I am rather surprised that you were asked to show that this particular function has no limit at zero. If I were your instructor I would have assigned the two part question where the first part is to prove that for the function $f(x) = x \sin(1/x)$, the limit $\lim_{x\to 0^+} f(x)$ exists. And the second part to prove that $\lim_{x\to 0^+} \mathrm{sgn}\circ f(x)$ does not exist. This way you can see the difference that the signum function makes.